# Swift_TransportException with code 451 on server side

Tags: php, email, server, yii2

I have this error from server. I try to send email in localhost and there is all right, all mail was sending. But when i upolad code on serwer i have this error time to time. This recognize my mail like Spam.

> Swift_TransportException
>
> Expected response code 250 but got code "451", with message "451 Ten
>   e-mail zostal zaklasyfikowanu jako spam. W przypadku pytan prosimy o
>   kontakt z naszymi konsultantami na stronie http://kontakt.o2.pl/ "

Here is my function send email:

```
public function getUser() {
       $user = User::findOne([
                    'status' => User::STATUS_DELETED,
                    'email' => $this->email,

        ]);

        return Url::to(['registration/confirm', 'key' => $user['auth_key']], true);
    }
    public function sendEmail() {

        $status = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('registrationmail',['url' => $this->getUser()])
                ->setTo($this->email)
                ->setCharset('utf8')
                ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => \Yii::$app->params['supportEmail']])
                ->setSubject(self::SUBJECT)
                ->send();


      return $status;
    }
```

And content of email:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $user common\models\User */
?>

<div class="wrapper" style="width:960px; margin:0 auto;">
        <div class="header" style="background:url('img/bg_header.png'); min-height:84px;">
            <div class="header-content" style="width:800px; margin:0 auto; padding-top:20px;">
                <a class="logo" href="" style="display:block; width:310px; height:50px; background:url('img/logo.png') no-repeat;"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-wrapper" style="background:url('img/conteng-bg.png'); padding-bottom:10px;">
            <div class="content" style="width:800px; margin:0 auto; padding-top:40px; color:#393838">
                <h1 style="margin:0; font-size:24px;">xxxxxxxxx</h1>
                <h2 style=" font-size:18px;">xxxxxxxx,</h2>
                <p style="font-size:14px;">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:</p>
                <p href="#" style="font-size:14px; color:#c69f61; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><?= Html::a(Html::encode($url), $url) ?></p>
                <p style="font-size:12px; font-style:italic; margin:60px 0 50px 0;">xxxxxxxxxx</p>

                <span style="display:block;  border-top:1px solid #a1a1a1; border-bottom: 1px solid #a1a1a1; font-size:12px; text-align:center; pxxxxxxxxxx <a href="mailto:xxxxx@xxxxxx.pl" style="color:#c69f61; ">xxxxx@xxxxx.pl</a></span>

                <p class="copyright" style="color:#807f7f; text-align:center; font-size:10px; margin-top:20px;">xxxxxxx © xxxxx 2016</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I write xxx where i have some data. Anyone know how to resolve this erron on server?

Answer (score -1):

`\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail']` should contain your username to http://poczta.o2.pl/